# C++ How to conditionally initialize a template class object?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class

```
template <typename T>
class myClass
{
   T variable;
....
};
```

I want to create an object of myClass , depending of some condition the object should either hold a string or int . how do I conditionally initialize like below :

```
if (condition1)
  myClass<userDefinedType1> x;
else
  myClass<userDefinedType2> x;
```

I don't think the code I wrote above is possible , but the problem is whether the type should be `userDefinedType1` or `userDefinedType2` is not known to me at compile time . How can I initialize the template class object when the type will only be known to me at run time based on user inputs  ?

Comment: Inheritance from a common base-class, polymorphism and dynamic allocation with smart pointers?

Comment: I think the title (and keywords) is misleading.  He's wanting to know the approach to use for a "sum type", and that the component types in question happen to be different instantiations of the same template is not significant or relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the type of the problem isn't known until runtime, then your options are limited.

If the number of possible instantiations is small/simple and you are using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or above, one option is to just use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```cpp
using MyClass = std::variant<std::monostate, myClass<userDefinedType1>,myClass<userDefinedType2>>;

auto v = MyClass{}; // create one without a value to start

if (condition) {
  v = myClass<userDefinedType1>{};
} else {
  v = myClass<userDefinedType2>{};
}
```

`std::variant` takes care of ensuring incorrect access does not occur (which prevents strict-aliasing violations), and it also will ensure that non-trivial destructors get invoked for the correctly instantiated types. This can then be used easily with `visit` assuming the functions that need to be called are homogeneously defined, since you can use a lambda with an `auto` parameter which will choose the correct type:

```cpp
std::visit([](auto& cls){
    cls.do_something();
}, v);
```

One other utility that can be used is [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), for a similar purpose:

```cpp
auto v = std::any{};

if (condition) {
  v = myClass<userDefinedType1>{};
} else {
  v = myClass<userDefinedType2>{};
}
```

The downside with `std::any` is that accessing the internal types is much more complicated and needs to be polled with `std::any_cast`. Still doable, but not so nice

---

Alternative, **polymorphism** is an option if your template might have some base-class that you can erase to. This may not work for every design, but in the case that it does you can simply use a `std::unique_ptr` to hold an instance to the base while you construct the class.

```cpp
class myClassBase {
    ...
    virtual auto common_api(...) -> void = 0;
    ...
};
template <typename T>
class myClass : public myClassBase {
    ...
    auto common_api(...) -> void override { ... }
    ...
};

...

auto v = std::unique_ptr<Base>{};
if (condition) {
    v = std::make_unique<myClass<userDefinedType1>>(...);
} else {
    v = std::make_unique<myClass<userDefinedType2>>(...);
}
```

---

The last real option is to perform some form of manual **type-erasure**, where you create a wrapper class that erases the template argument. This solution is *not* generic and will be highly-specific to the class itself for how it can be erased. This may involve something as simple as a polymorphic wrapper that erases the type in the implementation, or it can be more complex such as bound function-pointers that do more work.

Comment: How would get() functions work with the base-derived class approach ? for example if I have a function ```T getVar(){ return Var; }``` would I need to declare a virtual function for every possible type T can have in the base class ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, that would be the only way to do that through inheritance, since you can't make a function `template` be `virtual`. In that circumstance, you might be better off using `variant` instead -- since when you call `std::visit` you would get the exact type as requested. Or if your `T` types all satisfy some form of property, you may be able to erase the `T` type itself through some other means. Hard to say what is best without more details

Answer (score 1):

You can use a union.

```
union U {
    myClass<userDefinedType1> a;
    myClass<userDefinedType2> b;
};

U u;
if (condition1)
  u.a = myClass<userDefinedType1>();
else
  u.b = myClass<userDefinedType2>();
```

As stated in the comments, this compiles only if myClass has a trivial destructor, including the implicit destructor that will destruct T in myClass.

Comment: This doesn't work if `myClass` has a nontrivial destructor.

Comment: @Human-Compiler [not since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).  Though you'll have to write the union's destructor to destroy the proper member, which can be a bit of a puzzle.  Just use `std::variant`.

Comment: @JDługosz Even in C++11, you have to manually define the destructor (`~U()`) since it is [implicitly deleted](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e967ecTGc) if it contains non-trivial types. So the above code wouldn't even compile as-is unless the destructor is trivial (and this is before getting into manually calling the destructor to avoid UB)

Comment: Ah, right "this doesn't work" means the code in the post won't compile, not "unions can't have such members".

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the crazy world of template metaprogramming (TMP).  It's a lot easier now due to `constexpr` etc. but for programming the members of a class you still need to go old-school.

You have to generate your member by inheriting it from a base class.

That base class can be a template, including a fancy conditional TMP construct.  You can see this in some of the standard library classes.

Hmm, you want the *same* data member (`x`), just having a different type.  Well, that's easier:  Make it of type `T2`.  That can be generated using template stuff.  Something like this:

```
using T2 = std::conditional_t<condition1, userDefinedType1, userDefinedType2>;
myClass<T2> x;
```

> not known to me at compile time .

Well, that's another story.  You can't change the generated code *except* at compile time.

Do you want a variable `x` that can hold either of two types?

That can use Object Oriented techniques of having a common polymorphic base class with different derived types.

Or, you can use a `std::variant`.

A (primitive) `union` as Ozger's answer shows is basically a low-level unchecked version of the same idea.  In older versions of C++ such a `union` could not hold types that had constructors and destructors, but now they can, though you take on a lot of low-level effort.  It's basically the language back-end to make writing `variant` simpler.

Comment: OP says that the condition is not known at compile time. std::conditional_t will need compile time condition.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to store `x` for future usage,
you can make the code which applies to `x` template too, and then you branch looks like:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T);

// ...

if (condition1) {
    myClass<userDefinedType1> x;
    foo(x);
} else {
    myClass<userDefinedType2> x;
    foo(x);
}
```

You can even move `x` in the function template, so code would be:

```
template <typename T> void bar(T)
{
    myClass<T> x;
    // ...
}

// ...

if (condition1) {
    bar<userDefinedType1>();
} else {
    bar<userDefinedType2>();
}
```

If you need to store `x` for future usage, you need either to use `std::variant`, polymorphism base class or type erasure.

Answer (score -1):

Can't we just make class object dynamically. Something like this:

```
if (condition1)
  myClass<userDefinedType1>* x = new myclass<userDefined1>;
else
  myClass<userDefinedType2>* x = new myclass<userDefined2>;
```

Please let me know what's wrong with this approach

Comment: OP is asking for a way to use a single object type that may store _either_ one of two different types. Your answer is constructing two different and unrelated pointer types (because each instantiation of a template is a unique type). Dynamic objects _are_ a possible solution -- but this would require polymorphism and/or type-erasure -- but a base-class is not always possible when using templates. Additionally, smart pointers -- and C++11 -- have been around for *10 years*. There are few good reasons to manually be using `new` with regular pointers

Comment: @Human-Compiler Thanks for info, this is some new stuff for me, but I think I got the idea.